# Preg_split on 2 characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Im trying to split a string on 2 variables (T & +) which when using on "2018-06-25T10:32:00+01:00" will split it to:-

```
[0] => 2018-06-25
[1] => 10:32:00
[2] => 01:00
```

So I thought I could use "preg_split("/ (T|+) /", $ent)", but it itsnt working at all.

My code I have (in PHP) is:-

```
$ent = "2018-06-25T10:32:00+01:00";
print_r(preg_split("/ (T|\+) /", $ent));
```

Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the spaces

Comment: That worked, thank you :-)

Sorry, Im a newbie at this

Comment: *Why* do you parse dates using `regex`? PHP provides the [`DateTime` classes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) that do the job faster and safer than manual parsing. What is your exact use case?

Answer (score 2):

You have the problem in your regex. You can give it like below;

```
print_r(preg_split("/T|\+/", $ent));
```

Without using a regex, you can also use the php's Datetime class to split this into date and time (I prefer this).

```
$ent = '2018-06-25T10:32:00+02:00';
$datetime = new DateTime($ent);

$date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
$time = $datetime->format('H:i:s');
$offset = $datetime->getOffset() / 3600;

echo $date.'<br/>';
echo $time.'<br/>';
echo $offset.'<br/>';
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Parsing dates in PHP is not the best use case for `regex`. Maybe it is the best way to handle dates in other languages but **not in PHP**. PHP provides the [`DateTime` classes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) that handle the dates faster and safer than manual parsing.

This is how your code should look like:

```
$date = new DateTime("2018-06-25T10:32:00+01:00");

echo $date->format('Y-m-d'), "\n";
echo $date->format('H:i:s'), "\n";
echo $date->format('P'), "\n";
```

Check out the result: https://3v4l.org/gFvLp

Read more about the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Answer (score 0):

For your example you use an alternation with whitespaces `(T|\+)` which have meaning.

What you could do is remove the whitespaces and use `(T|\+)` or as an alternative use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[T+]`

```
$ent = "2018-06-25T10:32:00+01:00";
print_r(preg_split("/[T+]/", $ent));
```